# How to design Azure HDInsights Cluster

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

I have a query on AZURE HDInsights. How do I need to design AZURE HDInsights Cluster according to my on-premises infrastructure ? 
What are the major parameters which I need to consider before designing the cluster ? 
(For Example) If I have 100 servers running on-premises, how many nodes I need to select in my Cloud Cluster like that. ?!! In AWS we have EMR sizing calculator and Cluster Planner/Advisor. Do we have anything similar planning mechanism in AZURE apart from Pricing Calculator ? Please clarify and provide your inputs. With Any example will be really great. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.blue-granite.com/blog/how-to-choose-the-right-hdinsight-cluster

Answer (score -1):

Before deploying an HDInsight cluster, plan for the desired cluster capacity by determining the needed performance and scale. This planning helps optimize both usability and costs. Some cluster capacity decisions cannot be changed after deployment. If the performance parameters change, a cluster can be dismantled and re-created without losing stored data.

The key questions to ask for capacity planning are:

- In which geographic region should you deploy your cluster?
- How much storage do you need?
- What cluster type should you deploy?
- What size and type of virtual machine (VM) should your cluster nodes use?
- How many worker nodes should your cluster have?

Each and every question is addressed here: "[Capacity planning for HDInsight Clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-capacity-planning)".

Comment: Thanks @PRADEEP CHEEKATLA for your inputs.